# Footer doesn't show up in posts page

Tags: php, wordpress

I just bought and customized a commercial responsive wordpress theme called enfold.

So here's my issue. I created a page called blog and left it blank. There's an option in the page to display the footer and socket, so I clicked yes. In other pages in my site I also activated the footer and socket areas.

I used the "blog" page for my latest blog posts. The thing is the footer doesn't display in the blog page but in other pages / single posts page it works well. What could be the issue?

Someone told me from the support forum in enfold, and in other sites I have asked that it's a php memory issue.

I installed wp memory load and db usage plugin and my site loads like 22mb average per page, including the blog posts page.

I did this in the .htcacess file >

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

php_value memory_limit 96M

<<< should php value memory limit be on top of #end of wordpress ?

2.)

as for the wp-config.php should I put it here >>>

```
define('WP_CACHE', true); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', 'my site url' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

And lastly , is this issue related to php memory limit at all?

Hope someone here can help

Comment: It can be one of many things. Post output of `apt list --installed`

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Enfold options* in the *`admin > footer > Display the footer widgets & socket`*

If it is set like this already, then do it again, sometimes only needs to update.

That works for me.